# HTML string returning error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code here is working perfectly fine for the most part. `this.content` are strings of HTML comeing from JSON.

```
$(this.content).find('img, a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".jpeg"], a[href$=".JPEG"], a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".pdf"], a[href$=".PDF"]').each(function() {

});
```

For some reason though this string:

```
Packaged in lots of 10 sets
<img class="alignnone size-full" src="http://www.integra-adhesives.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Sink_Fastener.jpg" alt="" width="300" />
```

Is making jQuery cause a fit. It is throwing: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:`

I am using jQuery v2.1.1.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I've had this error before, if I can recall properly, has something to do with the unescaped forward slash. Will look in to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347611/jquery-client-side-template-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression

Comment: @lesssugar, I'm running 2.1.1, so the problem there is fixed already, but I did find a solution there anyhow. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `this.content = $.parseHTML(this.content);` beforehand.

As Barmar points out this is because jQuery is trying to use the string as a selector.

Comment: That's a nice solution, too.

Answer (score 2):

`$(something)` can work in two ways: if `something` is an HTML string, it parses it into DOM elements; if it's a selector, it searches the current DOM for elements matching that selector. If `something` begins with and HTML tag then it's an HTML string, otherwise it's assumed to be a selector. Your string begins with `Packaged`, which isn't an HTML tag, so the string is processed as a selector, and it's not a valid selector.

You should use:

```
$('<div>' + this.content).find(...);
```

so that the content will always be treated as HTML.

You even need to do this if the string does start with `<`, because `find()` only searches for descendants. If your string were something like:

```
<img src="someURL">
```

and you did:

```
$(this.content).find("img");
```

it wouldn't find it, because the image is the top-level element.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I found this out myself just before you posted your answer. I found a better way however of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that jQuery can't tell if your HTML is a selector expression or HTML.

From the jQuery docs (emphasis mine): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., **it starts with `<tag ... >`**). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as explained above.

So for your HTML to be recognized as HTML you should make sure it doesn't start with a text node. You could wrap all of your HTML in `<span></span>` tags just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks, I found this out myself and found using $.parseHTML fixes the issue.